# Preventing multiple clicks on a button in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have button in which user click on a button list is repeated multiple time in AngularJS?

Comment: @kapil soni you can disable the button on click of a button after some response you can again enable that button

Comment: sir please tell me how to re-enable after the response?

Answer (score 2):

You can either set a property and check it in `ngClick` or use the `ng-disabled` property for `buttons` - note that anchors cannot be disabled.

```
<button 
  ng-click="!isButtonClicked && (isButtonClicked=true) && clickButton()"
>Click Me Once</button>

<button 
  ng-click="(isButtonClicked=true) && clickButton()"
  ng-disabled="isButtonClicked"
>Click Me Once</button>
```

Or do both to get the UI from "disabled" with instant checking via the `$scope` property.

```
<button 
  ng-click="!isButtonClicked && (isButtonClicked=true) && clickButton()"
  ng-disabled="isButtonClicked"
>Click Me Once</button>
```

Comment: I (and likely every Angular developer on the planet) have tried this approach in the past. The problem is, it doesn't work fast enough--if you click fast enough, a second click will register before the button is disabled.

Comment: In that case check within the `clickButton()` function after a `$digest` cycle. You can wrap it in a `$timeout()` is probably the easiest way.

Comment: But the first method should be more or less instant - it is just setting a property on the `$scope` so it doesn't need to update the DOM to work.

Comment: Yeah, that's what we thought... :)

Comment: IIRC we did something similar to the `$timeout` and that was the most foolproof method. But interestingly it wasn't completely foolproof. No idea why.

Comment: Do you have example code? Changes to the $scope properties are atomic.

Comment: It was a while ago. One theory was that multiple click events aren't guaranteed to be separated by a digest cycle, and then the property wasn't updated fast enough (we were doing both). It still sounds like an implausible stretch, but we were definitely still occasionally getting multiple click events if we tried real hard.

Comment: ...however IIRC we were trying `setTimeout` and not `$timeout`. Maybe the semantics of `$timeout` is more foolproof.

Comment: The timeout and the property combo did make it work well enough. You **really** have to be trying to cause multiple clicks at that point. Disabling the button alone definitely didn't cut it though.

Comment: Looks like we used `setTimeout` and then in the callback `$scope.$apply`. Maybe using `$timeout` instead would have worked completely. Not gonna change it now. :)

Comment: TL;DR: disable button = not good enough; property = better (probably good enough); property + timeout = best (but not perfect).

Comment: #doublesharp, sir tell me how to implement this code our controller?